# Angular 2: Animate data in *ngFor?

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

I want to create a carousel like element, where on clicking next user navigates to next question after validation of the current input and same on click of previous. At the last question, the form is submitted and output is displayed.

The animation has to be of type ease-in/ease-out. Each question eases-in from right and on click of next, current question eases-out from left and simultaneously next question eases-in from right. Questions are in an array.

**Edited:**

HTML:

```
                <div [@questionAnimation]="orientation">
                    {{selectedQuestion.statement}}<br/>
                    {{selectedQuestion.helperText}}
                    <md-input [(ngModel)]="selectedQuestion.answer" type="{{selectedQuestion.type}}"
                              maxlength="{{selectedQuestion.maxLength}}"
                              min="{{selectedQuestion.min}}" max="{{selectedQuestion.max}}"
                              (keydown)="nextOnEnter($event)" required>
                        <span md-prefix [innerHTML]="selectedQuestion.prefix"></span>
                        <span md-suffix [innerHTML]="selectedQuestion.suffix"></span>
                    </md-input>
                </div>

                <button md-button (click)="prev()">Previous</button>
                <button md-button (click)="next()">Next</button>
```

Animations:

```
animations: [
        trigger('questionAnimation', [
            state('next', style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1.0})),
            state('prev', style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1.0})),
            transition('next => prev', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: 1.0}), animate('300ms')),
            transition('* => next', style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: 0.0}), animate('900ms'))
        ])
    ]
```

navigation code:

```
next() {
        this.orientation = 'next';
        let index = this.questions.indexOf(this.selectedQuestion);
        if (this.questions[index + 1]) {
            this.selectedQuestion = this.questions[index + 1];
        } else {
            this.calculate();
        }
    }

    prev() {
        this.orientation = 'prev';
        let index = this.questions.indexOf(this.selectedQuestion);
        if (this.questions[index - 1]) {
            this.selectedQuestion = this.questions[index - 1];
        } else {
            this.selectedQuestion = this.questions[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried? Where did you fail? Please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish and what you tried.

Comment: I have added the code but I am really doubtful that this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<ng-container *ngIf="questions && questions.length > 0">
    <div *ngFor="let question of questions" [@questionAnimation]="question.animationState">
        {{question.statement}}<br/>
        {{question.helperText}}
        <md-input [(ngModel)]="question.answer" type="{{question.type}}"
                  maxlength="{{question.maxLength}}"
                  min="{{question.min}}" max="{{question.max}}"
                  (keydown)="nextOnEnter($event)" required>
            <span md-prefix [innerHTML]="question.prefix"></span>
            <span md-suffix [innerHTML]="question.suffix"></span>
        </md-input>
    </div>

    <button md-button (click)="changeQuestion('prev')" *ngIf="currentQuestionIndex > 0">Previous</button>
    <button md-button (click)="changeQuestion('next')" *ngIf="currentQuestionIndex < (questions.length - 1)">Next</button>
</ng-container>
```

Animations

```
animations: [
      trigger('questionAnimation', [
        state('in', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
        state('out', style({ display: 'none' })),
        state('prevInactive', style({ display: 'none', opacity: 0 })),
        state('nextInactive', style({ display: 'none', opacity: 0 })),
        state('prevActive', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
        state('nextActive', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
        transition('* => prevActive', [
          style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: 1 }),
          animate('0.4s', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1 }))
        ]),
        transition('* => nextActive', [
          style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 1 }),
          animate('0.4s', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1 }))
        ]),
        transition('* => prevInactive', [
          style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)', opacity: 1 }),
          animate('0.4s', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0 }))
        ]),
        transition('* => nextInactive', [
          style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)', opacity: 1 }),
          animate('0.4s', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: 0 }))
        ])
      ])
]
```

Component

```
    private currentQuestionIndex: number;
    private questions: Question[];

    ngOnInit() {
      this.currentQuestionIndex = 0;
      this.questions = this.addAnimationState(questionsData, 0);
    }


    changeQuestion(direction: string) {
      this.questions[this.currentQuestionIndex].animationState = direction + 'Inactive';
      if (direction == 'next') {
        this.currentQuestionIndex++;
        if (this.currentQuestionIndex >= this.questions.length) {
          this.currentQuestionIndex = 0;
        }
      } else {
        this.currentQuestionIndex--;
        if (this.currentQuestionIndex < 0) {
          this.currentQuestionIndex = this.questions.length - 1;
        }
      }
      this.questions[this.currentQuestionIndex].animationState = direction + 'Active';
    }


    private addAnimationState(questionsData: Question[], index: number) {
      if(questionsData) {
        if(index >= questionsData.length) {
          index = questionsData.length - 1;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < questionsData.length; i++) {
          if (i == index) {
            questionsData[i].animationState = 'in';
          } else {
            questionsData[i].animationState = 'out';
          }
        }
        this.currentQuestionIndex = index;
      } else {
        questionsData = [];
        this.currentQuestionIndex = 0;
      }
      return questionsData;
    }
```

I didn't test it, if you have issues please comment here

Comment: what is `questionsData` here?

Comment: questionsData will have questions details, we are just adding animation state before assigning to this.questions, as this.questions are bind with view. so after adding necessary details we are assigning to this.questions